# openweathermap API to angular ES6

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6

I want to implement openweathermaps api to existing project but I'm having problems with adding some dependencies.

Current project is using ES6 (I think it's 1.5.x version of Angular) and I've installed via bower angular-openweathermap-api-factory module.

I'm getting this error: ReferenceError: openweathermapFactory is not defined
and I guess it's related to "Add jtt_openweathermap to your application's module dependencies." since I'm not sure how to add it to ES6 project.

Any help with this?

Comment: Can you share a code snippet of your malfunctioning code and the full error message?

Comment: Actually, see below for my answer on what I think is the cause.

Comment: I've used http request and pulled data from json. It works now. If I have time I'll try to implement it using module and post answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This tutorial](https://blog.khophi.co/simple-angularjs-weather-app/) appears to use the same API. Here's a [reference implementation](https://github.com/seanmavley/cc-weather-app) that seems to work.

Look at [this file](https://github.com/seanmavley/cc-weather-app/blob/master/app/app.js). Notice how, in line 1, the author imports the library into his angular module as `jtt_openweathermap`? The specific line of code looks something like this:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router', 'ngGeolocation', 'ngProgress', 'ui.router.title', 'jtt_openweathermap', 'ngMap'])
```

You need to do that too. I think you are probably not doing that. I would also take a look at this [controller code](https://github.com/seanmavley/cc-weather-app/blob/master/app/home/home.controller.js) here and make sure your imports are handled correctly as well.

Answer (score 0):

When I add jtt_openweathermap to controller file, I get blank page with no console errors:

```
 angular
.module('panorama', [
  'jtt_openweathermap'
])
.controller('PanoramaCtrl', PanoramaCtrl);
```

Comment: Does the controller also have the proper import for the weather app? See the controller code I posted. There is an explicit import for the weather app.